# Can I permanently change some default settings like inset size, remove doubles threshold, new mesh size?

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, bmesh

Ver. 2.79. I was hoping I could change some annoying settings by just editing some of the .PY files bundled with blender. Especially default inset amount. Maybe it's not that easy.

But for example, I see this file - "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\2.79\scripts\addons\mesh_inset__init__.py"

Within that file is this code:

```
inset_amount = FloatProperty(name="Amount",
    description="Amount to move inset edges",
    default=5.0,
```

I was hoping just changing that default might do what I want, but it doesn't seem to have any effect. Does anyone know if/how I can do this without having to recompile Blender?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to look in `User Preferences`, in `Input tab`. There is 2 different ways to do what.

First if your command called right from key-building. In this case you don't need to edit any python code, just go in Input tab, find command and here you can set any default settings as you like:

[image]

For example, I changed segments count. And after changing press `Save user settings`.

Second than your command called from menu, like <kbd>W</kbd> -> `Remove doubles`. You can also create a new shortcut and edit this settings like I explained before:

[image]

But of course it will affects only on new keybinding. So how to change default settings in menu? This time also go in Input tab, find command `Call Menu` that calls from keybinding (in case of `Remove doubles` it will be  <kbd>W</kbd> ):
[image]

And we interested in Name of menu (in our case it is "`VIEW3D_MT_edit_mesh_specials`")

This is what can search in files, and find menu like this:

```
class VIEW3D_MT_edit_mesh_specials(Menu):
    bl_label = "Specials"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        layout.operator_context = 'INVOKE_REGION_WIN'

        layout.operator("mesh.subdivide", text="Subdivide").smoothness = 0.0
        layout.operator("mesh.subdivide", text="Subdivide Smooth").smoothness = 1.0

        layout.separator()

        layout.operator("mesh.merge", text="Merge...")
        layout.operator("mesh.remove_doubles")

        layout.separator()

        layout.operator("mesh.hide", text="Hide").unselected = False
        layout.operator("mesh.reveal", text="Reveal")
        layout.operator("mesh.select_all", text="Select Inverse").action = 'INVERT'

        layout.separator()

        layout.operator("mesh.flip_normals")
        layout.operator("mesh.vertices_smooth", text="Smooth")
        layout.operator("mesh.vertices_smooth_laplacian", text="Laplacian Smooth")

        layout.separator()

        layout.operator("mesh.inset")
        layout.operator("mesh.bevel", text="Bevel")
        layout.operator("mesh.bridge_edge_loops")

        layout.separator()

        layout.operator("mesh.faces_shade_smooth")
        layout.operator("mesh.faces_shade_flat")

        layout.separator()

        layout.operator("mesh.blend_from_shape")
        layout.operator("mesh.shape_propagate_to_all")
        layout.operator("mesh.shortest_path_select")
        layout.operator("mesh.sort_elements")
        layout.operator("mesh.symmetrize")
        layout.operator("mesh.symmetry_snap")
```

I found this file here: `/usr/share/blender/2.79/scripts/startup/bl_ui/space_view3d.py`

This is a menu, that called from `Call Menu("VIEW3D_MT_edit_mesh_specials")`. Here you can add some default parameters.

Comment: Although it says to avoid comments like "thanks" I really want to thank you, Crantisz. I can't believe all this time I overlooked the fact that default settings can be changed in keybindings. The inset thing drove me crazy for so long. 

If I decide to edit e.g. space_view3d.py, do you know how I can find the syntax to write in my own new defaults? For example how would I specify a new merge distance for remove doubles, is it going to be similar to the subdivide smooth syntax? Something like .merge_distance  = 1.0 ?

Comment: @CreeDorofl on top panel you can find list of last used commands https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQF2F.jpg