# Changing default mesh size

Tags: dimensions

Sorry for asking, but I couldn't find my problem elsewhere.
I'd like to have the default dimension of newly created objects 20x20 instead of 2x2 units. The reason is, every time I create a new object, I have manually scale them up to my mostly needed size, which is 20mm.
Regardless of whether unit scale I select (mm or cm), the default cube is either 2mm or 0.2 cm, but I'd like to have a 20mm default cube.
Where can I change this?

Comment: You can scale the cube to your desired size and save that as the Startup File going in File > Defaults > Save Startup File.
If you want to change the size every time you create a new object in the scene, I don't know how, sorry.

Comment: You can scale the cube to your desired size and save that as the Startup File going in File > Defaults > Save Startup File.
If you want to change the size every time you create a new object in the scene, I don't know how, sorry.

Comment: If it's just for cubes, you could add your own shortcut with custom defaults for `mesh.primitive_cube_add` as shown here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/94285/can-i-permanently-change-some-default-settings-like-inset-size-remove-doubles-t

Comment: @RayMairlot thank you for the hint but sadly I'd like it for all primitives.

Answer (score 1):

In the *Scene Properties*, go to *Units*. Set *Unit Scale* to 0.01 and *Length* to *Milimeters*. Now the default cube and other objects are created with a size of 20mm.

[image: unit settings]

Comment: What's the reason here @Downvoter?

Answer (score 0):

This won't be an instantly workable answer, because this is an issue that I'm having trouble with, too.

But, it seems like you could maybe unregister the operators, then reregister them with your modifications. Checking out the Python API, I found: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.mesh.html

eg:

```
unregister()

    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=2.0, calc_uvs=True, enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), rotation=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0))

register()

    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=20.0, calc_uvs=True, enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), rotation=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0))
```

or something like that in an `__init__` file?

I hope you get an answer, as I'd like to do the same for meshes, but also clip distance for cameras!

Comment: Thank you, good idea,I will test it...